# Creating Automatic Hyperlinks in Outlook for specific words

Tags: microsoft-outlook, automation, hyperlink

Does anyone know how to create an automatic hyperlink in Outlook so when I type in that specific word a hyperlink will automatically attach itself to that word?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using editor's AutoCorrect feature. Just follow these steps:

1. Create a new email and type your word in the message text.
2. Select the whole word and insert a hyperlink using **Insert -> Hyperlink** ribbon button.
3. Again, select this hyperlinked word.
4. Open **File -> Options** window, select **Mail** tab and click **Editor Options...** button.
5. On the Editor Options window select **Proofing** tab and click **AutoCorrect Options...** button.
6. Select **With: Formatted text** option (now your selection has to appear in the **With:** text box), type short or full version of the word that will *trigger* the replacement in the **Replace:** text box and click **Add** button.
7. Click **OK, OK, OK, OK**.

Now you can type *trigger* word and it will be automatically replaced with hyperlinked version.

Answer (score 0):

[Auto-hyperlink in Outlook emails](http://knowoutlookpst.blogspot.com/2014/06/auto-hyperlink-outlook-email.html) can be added using the auto-correct option. Also, if the hyperlinks are not working, the there is possibility that web browsers are not properly set.